# How to create bean for EntityManagerFactoryBuilder automatically in non spring boot project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,@Qualifier("ds")DataSource datasource){
    return builder.dataSource(datasource).packages("com.entity").persistenceUnit("per").build();
}
```

I am trying to create bean for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  but I am getting error that no bean for EntityManagerFactoryBuilder  ... in spring boot bean for EntityManagerFactoryBuilder will created automatically using @EnableAutoConfiguration but how to do in non spring boot project .

complete code :

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder ;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder  ;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;



@Configuration

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class configclass {



    @Bean(name="cisEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cisEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,@Qualifier("dscis")DataSource datasource){

        return builder.dataSource(datasource).packages("com.cureissure.cis.entity").persistenceUnit("cis").build();
    }


    @Bean(name="dscis")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.ds_cis")
    public DataSource cisMysqlDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }



}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your spring configuration class?

Comment: I have posted my code please have a look .

Comment: found the solution? Same issue

Comment: For whatever reason the bean is missing in my SpringBootTest, while the application works correctly, which is why I´m running in the same issue now. (it occured after introducing multiple data sources in the application)